# Using same set of coding in different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a same set of coding that have to be used in different view controller.what I have to do, to avoid duplication of coding in every view controller.I couldn't find the exact solution in google.Can any one help me please.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
//NSLog(@"%d",rowno);

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.tranzlogix.com/tranzlogix_webservice/vehiclelist.php?format=json"];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *error;
//NSLog(@"%@",data);

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
//NSLog(@"%@",json);

results = [json valueForKey:@"posts"];
//NSLog(@"%@", results);
//NSLog(@"Count %d", results.count);

NSArray *res = [results valueForKey:@"post"];
//NSLog(@"%@", res);

Vehicle_No=[res valueForKey:@"vehicle_no"];
//NSLog(@"%@", Vehicle_No);

Vehicle_No_Org =[Vehicle_No objectAtIndex:rowno];
NSString *CellText=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Vehicle_No_Org];
//NSLog(@"%@",CellText);

//MAP VIEW WebService

NSString *urlMapString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.tranzlogix.com/tranzlogix_webservice/map.php?format=json&truckno=%@",CellText];

//NSLog(@"%@",urlMapString);

NSURL *urlMap=[NSURL URLWithString:urlMapString];
NSData *dataMap=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlMap];
NSError *errorMap;
//NSLog(@"%@",dataMap);

NSDictionary *jsonMap = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataMap options:kNilOptions error:&errorMap];
//NSLog(@"%@",jsonMap);

NSArray *resultsMap = [jsonMap valueForKey:@"posts"];
NSLog(@"%@", resultsMap);
//NSLog(@"Count %d", resultsMap.count);

NSArray *resMap = [resultsMap valueForKey:@"post"];
//NSLog(@"%@", resultsMap);

NSArray *latitudeString=[resMap valueForKey:@"latitude"];
NSLog(@"%@", latitudeString);
NSString *latOrgstring = [latitudeString objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", latOrgstring);
double latitude=[latOrgstring doubleValue];
//NSLog(@"latdouble: %f", latitude);


NSArray *longitudeString=[resMap valueForKey:@"longitude"];
NSLog(@"%@", longitudeString);
NSString *longOrgstring = [longitudeString objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", longOrgstring);
double longitude=[longOrgstring doubleValue];
NSLog(@"latdouble: %f", longitude);
```

This is what i need in more than two view controller one in map view and next in table view...

Comment: Inheritance? OOPs.. :P

Comment: please specify what do you mean by same set of coding and add some code as well

Comment: u can create a baseviewcontroller for common coding and inherit a baseviewcontroller to your view controller
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a base view controller with your main code and create subclasses of it.

For example, your main view controller would be:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
```

And then subclass it:

```
@interface OneViewController : MainViewController
```

Those subclasses will inherit the code.

Comment: Yes, if I have the coding in the main view controller and in the next view controller i have to use the latitude and longitude values to locate in the map.For that what i have to do.

Comment: Createte them as public variables (declare them in your interface file .h) and they will be inherited

Comment: I have to declare it in the mainviewcontroller.h right?

Comment: Yes, declare them as properties there and they will be inherited.

Comment: If you have any INHERITANCE example coding can you send it to me pls...my mail id is sukesh_nice@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 0):

```
Here you can use Custom Delegates in ios..

just create Custom Delegate(Protocol) in AppDelegate or Singleton Class.Here im using AppDelegate

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


**AppDeleagte.h**

@protocol parserDelegate <NSObject>


-(void)sendDataToCorrespondingViewController:(id)data andServiceName:(NSString *)serviceName;

@end

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic,strong) id <parserDelegate> delegate;


-(void)getMethodURL:(NSString *)urlString andServiceName:(NSString *)serviceName;

@end


**AppDeleagte.m**

//Implementing getMethod() in AppDelegate.m File

-(void)getMethodURL:(NSString *)urlString andServiceName:(NSString *)serviceName;
{



    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSError *error;
    {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 2), ^{


            NSData *data =[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];

            if (data == nil) {

                NSLog(@"error bcz data is nil:%@",error.localizedDescription);
            }
            else
            {

                NSError *error;
                id response =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

                [self.delegate sendDataToCorrespondingViewController:response andServiceName:serviceName];


            }
        });

    }
}


Now import AppDelegate in required ViewController and Create instance For AppDelegate

**ViewController.h**

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<parserDelegate>
{

}
@property (nonatomic,strong) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@end


**ViewController.m**

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize appDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    self.appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.appDelegate.delegate=self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(IBAction)getSeviceData:(id)sender
{
    //call AppDeleagte method for Webservice

    [self.appDelegate getMethodURL:@"http://www.tranzlogix.com/tranzlogix_webservice/vehiclelist.php?format=json" andServiceName:@"VehicleList"];

}
//implement Deleagte method
-(void)sendDataToCorrespondingViewController:(id)data andServiceName:(NSString *)serviceName
{
    NSLog(@"response data: %@",data); //Here is the response from websevice
    NSLog(@"serviceName: %@",serviceName); // Here Service name differentiate,if we call 2   webservices in ViewController
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```